# Inheriting ActionBarSherlock theme crashes eclipse layout editor

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock, stack-overflow

I'm using ActionBarSherlock in my Android project, and it's awesome. One small issue: My app theme inherits from `Sherlock.Theme.Light.DarkActionBar`, which is fine to do and it will run as expected. The problem is whenever I try to open any of my layout files in the Eclipse editor, it throws up a StackOverFlowError.

The only way to get rid of that is to change the style/theme being used to preview the layout (in the dropdown box up in the right corner), but then I don't get to preview it the way it will actually look. Is there a way to fix this?

Here's what the error log shows:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.regex.Pattern.atom(Pattern.java:1952)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:1834)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1752)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1460)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1133)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:823)
at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2292)
at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2334)
at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceResolver.findResValue(ResourceResolver.java:206)
at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceResolver.resolveResValue(ResourceResolver.java:325)
at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceResolver.resolveResValue(ResourceResolver.java:333)
at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceResolver.resolveResValue(ResourceResolver.java:333)
at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceResolver.resolveResValue(ResourceResolver.java:333)
at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceResolver.resolveResValue(ResourceResolver.java:333)
at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceResolver.resolveResValue(ResourceResolver.java:333)
at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceResolver.resolveResValue(ResourceResolver.java:333)
... and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` in the layout editor for a comparable look. This is a bug in ADT.

See: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19599

Comment: Well, if anybody would know, it'd be you, so <check>